# Pandas use contains for a specific word excluding similar words

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am filtering a string using `Result[Results['Subject'].str.contains('lock')]` but I need to esclude words like "clock"
What I need is the sting staring with "lock", ending as " lock" or containing " lock "
Many thanks

Comment: `df.String.str.contains(r'\block\b',regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex word delimiter `\b`:

```
Results[Results['Subject'].str.contains(r'\block\b')]
```

Example input:

```
Results = pd.DataFrame({'Subject': ['lock', 'clock', 'abc lock', 'locker']})
```

Output:

```
    Subject
0      lock
2  abc lock
```